# How to get all layers from Keras Model with TensorFlow hub

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I use efficientnetv2 from `hub.KerasLayer`, I would like to see all layers when using `model.summary()`, but it shows only *"keras_layer (KerasLayer)"*

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| keras_layer (KerasLayer) | (None, 1280) | 5919312 |
| dropout (Dropout) | (None, 1280) | 0 |
| dense (Dense) | (None, 2) | 2562 |

Answer (score 1):

This way you can "jump inside" the model;

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

malli = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/efficientnet_v2_imagenet21k_b0/feature_vector/2")
print("Thickness of the model:", len(malli.weights))
for i in range(len(malli.weights)):
    print("In layer ",malli.weights[i].name," the content is: ", malli.weights[i])
```

...of course note the output is quite a loooong but modify the output print according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow's [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) is essentially a computation graph. While you could in principle inspect its structure, there is no information about high-level architectural blocks.

If you'd like to access individual layers, a better option might be using the model from the authors' [original implementation](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientnetv2). It can be constructed as follows:

```python
from effnetv2_model import get_model
model = get_model('efficientnetv2-s', weights='imagenet21k-ft1k', with_endpoints=True)
```

Pretrained weights are available for the same configurations as in [TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/collections/efficientnet_v2). `model.summary()` displays individual (Fused)MBConv blocks.

Also note that a future version of TensorFlow [will include](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet_v2/EfficientNetV2S) EfficientNet v2 (already available in nightly builds).